# In the Heckman Model, why shouldn't I use the dependent variable from the selection equation as an independent variable in the outcome equation?

Tags: r, heckman

Why shouldn't I use the dependent variable from the selection equation as an independent variable in the outcome equation when using the Heckman Model?
I've seen this done in the literature (where the inverse Mills Ratio appears with the dependent variable from the selection equation, I've even seen them as an interaction term, e.g. IMR*ICW, in this case ICW approximates lfp), but I incur singularity issues that prevent a solution when I try to run this in R.

Comment: If you don't wrap $\lambda()$ around the first-stage prediction, you will have perfect collinearity between that prediction and the second-stage regressors. The non-linearity of $\lambda()$ is what drives the identification, particularly without an exclusion restriction.

Comment: @ Dimitriy. Thanks, I somewhat understand and now I know that there is a way to do it. Would you, by any chance, know the R code I would use to wrap λ() around the first-stage prediction? Thanks in advance for any further guidance.

Comment: @Dimitriy. Can you elaborate? I don't understand as well as I first thought.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were doing before. Please ignore my first comment (though it is a true statement). If you include an interaction between the IMR and the selection equation outcome in the wage equation, that outcome will always be one since the wage is only observed for those who are participating. Since it's always one, you will have collinearity.